# Communication between Android App and UIAutomator via Non-UI mechanism

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

Currently I am using UIAutomator to test our application and all UI elements are accessible by UIAutomator.

Usually build APK with additional code to show dialog, indicating successful completion of test-case (i.e. operation invoked by UIAutomator), to inform UIAutomator to proceed with next test-case.

Code which is responsible to show dialog is not committed into repository and maintained as patches and not allowed to be committed in repository.
For this reason, whenever we want to execute UIAutomator tests, we build APK with additional code residing in patches.

**My question:** Is there any other way to communicate UIAutomator about successful completion of test-case (i.e. application has completed the operation invoked by UIAutomator), without using dialog.

I need this change to execute UIAutomator tests on release-candidate builds.

**What I tried:**  Set constant delay between test-cases invocation.

But I cannot set constant delay between test-cases, as execution time varies based on test-data and device/environment.

I thought of BroadcastReceiver, but I don't know how to register from UIAutomator?

Is there any other mechanism / workaround to achieve this functionality?

Comment: I don't think you can register BroadcastReceiver from Uiautomator testcase. One way is to invoke Uiautomator test case from a batch file and after each test case execution check the status and proceed with next test case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you really asks for, but since I am not allowed to comment, you can correct me if I have misunderstood.

You are looking  for a way to assert that a testcase has executed and no anomalies been present in your application?

First you need to identify a [UiObject](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiObject.html). Then you can make use of

```
UiObject.waitForExists();
```

Above method will return true when a uiObject matches the query specified on instantiation.

Another solution is to use a runner which can extend [UiAutomatorInstrumentationTestRunner](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/uiautomator/+/61ce05bd4fd5ffc1f036c7c02c9af7cb92d6ec50/src/com/android/uiautomator/testrunner/UiAutomatorInstrumentationTestRunner.java), where you build a TestSuite to execute in set order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the UiAutomator to report status to the Host console, here is a answer from the post below.

[Writing to Android UI Automator output console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453501/writing-to-android-ui-automator-output-console)

[Instrumentation.sendStatus(..)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#sendStatus(int,%20android.os.Bundle))

Each key / value pair in the Bundle will be written out like this:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: key1=value1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: key2=value2
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
```

So, your host can get status in any steps you want.