# Writing to Android UI Automator output console

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am writing a small wrapper over Android UI Automator. Normally we can see the test case status in the console. Can I access it and add my own messages? I have tried `System.out.println`. But it did not work. 
Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'UIAutomator output console'?

Comment: In android studio, UIAutomator displays the test result in the JUnit console. I meant that.

Comment: Hi! I've updated my answer according to my ideas about junit (although I haven't use that:))

Comment: Are you using UiAutomator 2.0 or higher?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Instrumentation.sendStatus(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#sendStatus(int%2C%20android.os.Bundle)) report information to the console.

sendStatus(..) takes a Bundle and a status code as arguments. It won't let you write a string directly to the console, but each key / value pair in the Bundle will be written out like this:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: key1=value1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: key2=value2
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
```

Note: This will only work if you're using a recent version of UiAutomator (2.0+). The old version does not have access to Instrumentation, so if you're using shell-based UiAutomator it's time to upgrade!

Comment: can you post a code snippit as to how this can be implemented in a uiautomator test

Answer (score 2):

The  [Instrumentation.sendStatus(..)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#sendStatus(int,%20android.os.Bundle)) can be used to write to the uiautomator console.

Quick example will be:

```
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("MyResult","10");
   getAutomationSupport().sendStatus(0, bundle);
```

Hope this is what your looking for!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use Java's print statement, you should import:

```
 import static java.lang.System.out;
```

After you do the import, then you can use:

```
out.println("hello world");
```